# Designer.cs file not generated on sub-classing a subclass of System.Windows.Form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I had a Form "ParentForm" Designed in C# VS2010 with two buttons.

I wanted five forms to have the same two buttons, so i decided to write five *.cs files(subForm1.cs,subForm2.cs...subForm5.cs) derived from the "ParentForm" as base class.

Now VS2010 shows these derived classes with a form icon(ie recognizes as Forms), but does not generate a .designer.cs file for it. So the problem I am facing is that, whenever I drag a

Control into derived class form say subForm1.cs , VS2010 puts the auto-generated code into my subForm1.cs instead of subForm1.Designer.cs. Although I tried manually creating a file named subForm1.Designer.cs (which also gets detected and is put under the hierarchy of the Form icon in solution explorer) but, still the auto-generated code goes to the subForm1.cs file.  How do

I tell VS2010 to patch subForm1.cs+subForm1.Designer.cs+subForm1.resx as one form subForm1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the designer file, Add new `Windows Forms`.
Then replace the inheritance from `Form` class to your `ParentForm` class.

This way any new controls you add to your child form should get added in the designer file.

Also please go through this link on [Visual Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there some other way to use a Form as a template for other forms? That was  my ultimate goal.

Comment: You can create a form that meets your requirements and then export it as a template. You can then share this zip file with others in the team so everyone can use it. Refer -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s365byhx(v=vs.100).aspx